# Can't get Plaid Link to Open using Javascript and python

Tags: javascript, python, flask, plaid

When the plaid link handler is called it spins and then goes away. I can't get the link dialog box to show completely to get access token. Setup using flask for the python server on port 5000 and using the plaid api for calls in python. Using javascript on the client side.

I can see the requests going through but nothing happens or seems to post to the client:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Apr/2022 21:53:31] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Apr/2022 21:54:10] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Apr/2022 21:54:10] "POST /create_link_token HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Javascript:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>    
      </head>
      <body>
        <button id="link-button">Link Account</button>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.plaid.com/link/v2/stable/link-initialize.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    (async function($) {
      var handler = Plaid.create({
        // Create a new link_token to initialize Link
        token: (await $.post('/create_link_token')).link_token,
        receivedRedirectUri: window.location.href,
        onLoad: function() {
          // Optional, called when Link loads
        },
        onSuccess: function(public_token, metadata) {
          // Send the public_token to your app server.
          // The metadata object contains info about the institution the
          // user selected and the account ID or IDs, if the
          // Account Select view is enabled.
          $.post('/exchange_public_token', {
            public_token: public_token,
          });
        },
        onExit: function(err, metadata) {
          // The user exited the Link flow.
          if (err != null) {
            // The user encountered a Plaid API error prior to exiting.
          }
          // metadata contains information about the institution
          // that the user selected and the most recent API request IDs.
          // Storing this information can be helpful for support.
        },
        onEvent: function(eventName, metadata) {
          // Optionally capture Link flow events, streamed through
          // this callback as your users connect an Item to Plaid.
          // For example:
          // eventName = "TRANSITION_VIEW"
          // metadata  = {
          //   link_session_id: "123-abc",
          //   mfa_type:        "questions",
          //   timestamp:       "2017-09-14T14:42:19.350Z",
          //   view_name:       "MFA",
          // }
        }
      });
      $('#link-button').on('click', function(e) {
        handler.open();
      });
    })(jQuery);
    </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Python server.py:

```
    # source /Users/tnappy/node_projects/quickstart/python/bin/activate
    # Read env vars from .env file
    from plaid.exceptions import ApiException
    from plaid.model.payment_amount import PaymentAmount
    from plaid.model.payment_amount_currency import PaymentAmountCurrency
    from plaid.model.products import Products
    from plaid.model.country_code import CountryCode
    from plaid.model.recipient_bacs_nullable import RecipientBACSNullable
    from plaid.model.payment_initiation_address import PaymentInitiationAddress
    from plaid.model.payment_initiation_recipient_create_request import PaymentInitiationRecipientCreateRequest
    from plaid.model.payment_initiation_payment_create_request import PaymentInitiationPaymentCreateRequest
    from plaid.model.payment_initiation_payment_get_request import PaymentInitiationPaymentGetRequest
    from plaid.model.link_token_create_request_payment_initiation import LinkTokenCreateRequestPaymentInitiation
    from plaid.model.item_public_token_exchange_request import ItemPublicTokenExchangeRequest
    from plaid.model.link_token_create_request import LinkTokenCreateRequest
    from plaid.model.link_token_create_request_user import LinkTokenCreateRequestUser
    from plaid.model.asset_report_create_request import AssetReportCreateRequest
    from plaid.model.asset_report_create_request_options import AssetReportCreateRequestOptions
    from plaid.model.asset_report_user import AssetReportUser
    from plaid.model.asset_report_get_request import AssetReportGetRequest
    from plaid.model.asset_report_pdf_get_request import AssetReportPDFGetRequest
    from plaid.model.auth_get_request import AuthGetRequest
    from plaid.model.transactions_get_request import TransactionsGetRequest
    from plaid.model.transactions_get_request_options import TransactionsGetRequestOptions
    from plaid.model.identity_get_request import IdentityGetRequest
    from plaid.model.investments_transactions_get_request_options import InvestmentsTransactionsGetRequestOptions
    from plaid.model.investments_transactions_get_request import InvestmentsTransactionsGetRequest
    from plaid.model.accounts_balance_get_request import AccountsBalanceGetRequest
    from plaid.model.accounts_get_request import AccountsGetRequest
    from plaid.model.investments_holdings_get_request import InvestmentsHoldingsGetRequest
    from plaid.model.item_get_request import ItemGetRequest
    from plaid.model.institutions_get_by_id_request import InstitutionsGetByIdRequest
    from plaid.model.transfer_authorization_create_request import TransferAuthorizationCreateRequest
    from plaid.model.transfer_create_request import TransferCreateRequest
    from plaid.model.transfer_get_request import TransferGetRequest
    from plaid.model.transfer_network import TransferNetwork
    from plaid.model.transfer_type import TransferType
    from plaid.model.transfer_user_in_request import TransferUserInRequest
    from plaid.model.ach_class import ACHClass
    from plaid.model.transfer_create_idempotency_key import TransferCreateIdempotencyKey
    from plaid.model.transfer_user_address_in_request import TransferUserAddressInRequest
    from plaid.api import plaid_api
    from flask import Flask
    from flask import render_template
    from flask import request
    from flask import jsonify
    from datetime import datetime
    from datetime import timedelta
    import plaid
    import base64
    import os
    import datetime
    import json
    import time
    from dotenv import load_dotenv
    from werkzeug.wrappers import response
    import pyodbc 
    
    load_dotenv()
    
    
    app = Flask(__name__)
    
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
                          "Server=DESKTOP-DJCMSVC\MJBOURQUIN_SQL;"
                          "Database=MyBudget;"
                          "Trusted_Connection=yes;")
    
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM Accounts')
    for row in cursor:
        print('row = %r' % (row,))
    vals = ("SOMETHING")
    data = "UPDATE Accounts Set API_ID = 'SOMETHING' WHERE Id = 1"
    cursor.execute(data)
    cursor.commit();
    
    access = "THAT THING"
    cursor = cnxn.execute('UPDATE Accounts Set API_ID = ? WHERE Id = ?', [access,1])
    cursor.commit();
    
    
    # Fill in your Plaid API keys - https://dashboard.plaid.com/account/keys
    PLAID_CLIENT_ID = os.getenv('PLAID_CLIENT_ID')
    PLAID_SECRET = os.getenv('PLAID_SECRET')
    # Use 'sandbox' to test with Plaid's Sandbox environment (username: user_good,
    # password: pass_good)
    # Use `development` to test with live users and credentials and `production`
    # to go live
    PLAID_ENV = os.getenv('PLAID_ENV', 'sandbox')
    # PLAID_PRODUCTS is a comma-separated list of products to use when initializing
    # Link. Note that this list must contain 'assets' in order for the app to be
    # able to create and retrieve asset reports.
    PLAID_PRODUCTS = os.getenv('PLAID_PRODUCTS', 'transactions').split(',')
    
    # PLAID_COUNTRY_CODES is a comma-separated list of countries for which users
    # will be able to select institutions from.
    PLAID_COUNTRY_CODES = os.getenv('PLAID_COUNTRY_CODES', 'US').split(',')
    
    products = []
    for product in PLAID_PRODUCTS:
        products.append(Products(product))
    
    def empty_to_none(field):
        value = os.getenv(field)
        if value is None or len(value) == 0:
            return None
        return value
    
    host = plaid.Environment.Sandbox
    
    if PLAID_ENV == 'sandbox':
        host = plaid.Environment.Sandbox
    
    if PLAID_ENV == 'development':
        host = plaid.Environment.Development
    
    if PLAID_ENV == 'production':
        host = plaid.Environment.Production
    
    # Parameters used for the OAuth redirect Link flow.
    #
    # Set PLAID_REDIRECT_URI to 'http://localhost:3000/'
    # The OAuth redirect flow requires an endpoint on the developer's website
    # that the bank website should redirect to. You will need to configure
    # this redirect URI for your client ID through the Plaid developer dashboard
    # at https://dashboard.plaid.com/team/api.
    PLAID_REDIRECT_URI = empty_to_none('PLAID_REDIRECT_URI')
    
    configuration = plaid.Configuration(
        host=host,
        api_key={
            'clientId': PLAID_CLIENT_ID,
            'secret': PLAID_SECRET,
            'plaidVersion': '2020-09-14'
        }
    )
    
    api_client = plaid.ApiClient(configuration)
    client = plaid_api.PlaidApi(api_client)
    
    @app.route('/')
    def index():
      return render_template('index.html')
    
    @app.route('/my-link/')
    def my_link():
      print ('I got clicked!')
    
      return 'Click.'
    
    @app.route("/create_link_token", methods=['POST'])
    def create_link_token():
        # Get the client_user_id by searching for the current user
            request = LinkTokenCreateRequest(
                products=products,
                client_name="Budgetary",
                country_codes=list(map(lambda x: CountryCode(x), PLAID_COUNTRY_CODES)),
                language='en',
                user=LinkTokenCreateRequestUser(
                    client_user_id=str(time.time())
                )
            )
            if PLAID_REDIRECT_URI!=None:
                request['redirect_uri']=PLAID_REDIRECT_URI
        # create link token
            response = client.link_token_create(request)
            return jsonify(response.to_dict())
    
    @app.route('/exchange_public_token', methods=['POST'])
    def exchange_public_token():
        global access_token
        public_token = request.form['public_token']
        request = ItemPublicTokenExchangeRequest(
          public_token=public_token
        )
        response = client.item_public_token_exchange(request)
        access_token = response['access_token']
        item_id = response['item_id']
    
        cursor = cnxn.execute('UPDATE Accounts Set API_ID = ? WHERE Id = ?', [access_token,1])
        cursor.commit();
    
        return jsonify(response.to_dict())
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
      app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: A couple of troubleshooting thoughts: Can you confirm that you successfully got a link token by logging the value of the link_token? Are there any JavaScript errors in the browser console?

Answer (score -2):

Solved by breaking the code out into pieces. Clicking the button, then requesting and printing value in python. Then sending and making sure it's parsed correctly. Then with the parsed token value opening up link successfully.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).